# req.isAuthenticated() is always returning false even when user is authenticated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, ejs

I am creating an application with node.js, express.js, passport.js, ejs and MongoDB.

here is my code:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.email,
    fname: req.body.fname,
    lname: req.body.lname,
    password: req.body.password
  })
  req.login(user, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.redirect('/signup')
  }
  else{
    passport.authenticate('local', function(error, user, info){
      req.session.save(function(){
        res.redirect('/secretPage');
      })
    })(req, res)
  }
})
})

app.get('/secretPage', function(req, res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.render('page')
    console.log('user authenticated');
  }
  else{
    res.redirect('/login')
    console.log('user not authenticated');
  }
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
})
```

here is my express-session setup:

```
const session = require('express-session')

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitalized: false,
}));
```

For some reason, even though the user gets successfully authenticated on the /login route, when the user is redirected to /secretPage req.isAuthenticated() is still false. Please help solve this problem.

Comment: This is most likely related to your express-session setup. Hard to say for sure without the setup code for that though.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the express-session setup. I might be wrong...

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: i dont see anything wrong in the code

Comment: @MoritzMahringer